# String Aritmatic using character operators but not using eval

Tags: matlab, eval

I am trying to write a shortest function code than can add / multiply / divide / subtract them. The only thing is that the operation would be provided in a char data type:

```
+ = '+'
- = '-'
/ = '/'
* = '*'
```

I have successfully implemented the same where operator = '+':

```
>> eval(sprintf('%d %c %d',8, operator, 7))

ans =

    15
```

But is there a way without using 'eval' function we can achieve the same?

====UPDATE=======

The below is what I could reduce :

```
function value = MathsOperations(numbers,operator)  
  value(operator == '+') = numbers(1) + numbers(2);
  value(operator == '-') = numbers(1) - numbers(2);
  value(operator == '*') = numbers(1) * numbers(2);
  value(operator == '/') = numbers(1) / numbers(2);
end
```

How still I can reduce the LOC(lines of code)?

Comment: You can simply define *functions*.

Comment: Agreed but can the same be achieved in one function within 2-3 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map=containers.Map({'+','-','*','/'},{@plus,@minus,@mtimes,@mdivide});
f=map('+');
value=f(numbers(1),numbers(2))
```

Comment: Nice use of containers.Map!

Comment: Just a small change it should be \@mrdivide instead of \@mdivide